# Laravel 5.2 and Braintree Custom Webhooks

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, braintree

I'm using Braintree to collect payments for a SaaS subscription site built using Laravel 5.2 and testing it on my localhost using ngrok.io. The signup and initial charges work fine.  I can cancel and resume subscriptions, as well. However, I can't get the custom webhooks to work.  I'm following the Laravel docs. Here's my code:

routes.php

```
Route::post('/webhook/braintree', 'BraintreeWebhookController@handleWebhook');
```

BraintreeWebhookController.php

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    use App\Http\Requests;
    use Braintree\WebhookNotification;
    use Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController;
    use App\Transaction;

class BraintreeWebhookController extends WebhookController
{
    //
    public function handleSubscriptionChargedSuccessfully(WebhookNotification $notification)
    {
        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->subscript_id = $notification->subscription->id;
        $transaction->name = $notification->subscription->name;
        $transaction->next_bill_date = $notification->subscription->next_bill_date;
        $transaction->price = $notification->subscription->price;
        $transaction->save();

        return new Response('Webhook Handled', 200);
    }

    public function handleSubscriptionChargedUnsuccessfully(WebhookNotification $notification)
    {
        //
    }

    public function handleSubscriptionTrialEnded(WebhookNotification $notification)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

The Braintree Webhooks Test URL link returns "Success! Server responded with 200." I tested the Transaction model using a test form and it creates a database record just fine. Is the Subscription_Charged_Successfully webhook not making it through to the controller or am I missing something in the handle function? Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty much doing the same as what you've got here. I'm using ngrok to test my local setup with braintree and I've figured out there's an exception with your code.

```
ErrorException: Undefined property on Braintree\Subscription: name in file /var/www/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree/Base.php on line 49
```

Looks like name is not a property on subscription object

I figured out that you can get your local subscription like so

```
$localSubscription = Subscription::where('braintree_id', $notification->subscription->id)
            ->first();

Transaction::create([
    'subscription_id' => $notification->subscription->id,
    'name' => $localSubscription->name,
    'next_bill_date' => $notification->subscription-> nextBillingDate,
    'price' => $notification->subscription->price,
    'user_id' => $localSubscription->user->id,
]);
```

Where `Subscription` is `Laravel\Cashier\Subscription`.

**EDIT**

Also `next_bill_date` should be `nextBillingDate` as seen above.